# Hive external table is not showing any data even when the parquet files associated with that are present

Tags: hive, pyspark, hiveql

I have created an external hive table with partitions as following-

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS engine_power( 
engine_company              string,
engine_model_name           string,
power_timestamp             timestamp,
rotor_efficiency            float,
rotor_power         float,
rotor_speed             float) 
PARTITIONED BY (year int, month int, day int) STORED AS PARQUET 
location '/powerCalculation' ;
```

After that I am performing some calculations in pyspark and then writing the final dataframe to a parquet file as below-

```
df.write.partitionBy('year','month','day').parquet("/powerCalculation",mode='append')
```

It is creating the parquet files at the said location with new folder for year, month and day but when I am querying the table it is not showing any data,`select * from engine_power` is not returning any rows.It is just giving the columns with no data in it. After searching various articles if I issue the statement

```
MSCK REPAIR TABLE engine_power;
```

I am getting the updated rows. Do I need to give this everytime I write the data to the partitioned table? Is there any other way that this updation can happen automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no automatic option to refresh partitions, the approach I used is defining additional Hive action as part of the Oozie workflow after the job creating a daily parquet file successful run.

Comment: So I guess I have to run that MSCK repair statement each time I create a new parquet file

Comment: not a single file but when you create a new partition folder. Usually, the parquet files created in an incremental way on an hourly or daily basis.